# How to do regression (simple linear for example) in polars select or groupby context?

Tags: python, python-polars

I am using polars in place of pandas. I am quite amazed by the speed and lazy computation/evaluation. Right now, there are a lot of methods on lazy dataframe, but they can only drive me so far.

So, I am wondering what is the best way to use polars in combination with other tools to achieve more complicated operations, such as regression/model fitting.

To be more specific, I will give an example involving linear regression.

Assume I have a polars dataframe with columns day, y, x1 and x2, and I want to generate a series, which is the residual of regressing y on x1 and x2 group by day. I have included the code example as follows and how it can be solved using pandas and statsmodels. How can I get the same result with the most efficiency using idiomatic polars?

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

def regress_resid(df, yvar, xvars):
    result = sm.OLS(df[yvar], sm.add_constant(df[xvars])).fit()
    return result.resid

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "y": [1, 6, 3, 2, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3],
        "x1": [1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 7, 3],
        "x2": [8, 5, 3, 6, 3, 7, 3, 2, 9, 1],
    }
)

df.groupby("day").apply(regress_resid, "y", ["x1, "x2])
# day
# 1    0    0.772431
#      1   -0.689233
#      2   -1.167210
#      3   -0.827896
#      4    1.911909
# 2    5   -0.851691
#      6    1.719451
#      7   -1.167727
#      8    0.354871
#      9   -0.054905
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add an example with input data and your desired output dataframe?

Maybe you can show how you would do it in pandas?

Comment: added a code example. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple columns to a function, you have to pack them into a `Struct` as polars expression always map from `Series -> Series`.

Because polars does not use `numpy` memory which `statsmodels` does, you must convert the polars types `to_numpy`. This is often free in case of 1D structures.

Finally, the function should not return a numpy array, but a polars `Series` instead, so we convert the result.

```py
import polars as pl
from functools import partial
import statsmodels.api as sm

def regress_resid(s: pl.Series, yvar: str, xvars: list[str]) -> pl.Series:
    df = s.struct.unnest()
    yvar = df[yvar].to_numpy()
    xvars = df[xvars].to_numpy()
    
    result = sm.OLS(yvar, sm.add_constant(xvars)).fit()
    return pl.Series(result.resid)
    

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "y": [1, 6, 3, 2, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3],
        "x1": [1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 7, 3],
        "x2": [8, 5, 3, 6, 3, 7, 3, 2, 9, 1],
    }
)

(df.group_by("day")
   .agg(
       pl.struct(["y", "x1", "x2"]).map_elements(partial(regress_resid, yvar="y", xvars=["x1", "x2"]))
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very helpful. How about the performance considerations? Does 'apply a custom function' come with some performance costs? If so, how much? How do you think if Polars implement commonly used regression functionalities natively?

Comment: How to explode the result and align with original dataframe?

Comment: @lebesgue use `.explode`

Answer (score 5):

Since all you're asking for is simple linear regression residuals, we can do this with just a few Polars expressions:

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

# create some correlated data
generator = np.random.default_rng(seed=4)
x = generator.normal(size=100)
error = generator.normal(size=100)
df = pl.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": 2 + x + error})

def residuals(x: pl.Expr, y: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    # e_i = y_i - a - bx_i
    #     = y_i - ȳ + bx̄ - bx_i
    #     = y_i - ȳ - b(x_i - x̄)
    x_mean = x.mean()
    y_mean = y.mean()
    x_demeaned = x - x.mean()
    y_demeaned = y - y.mean()
    x_demeaned_squared = x_demeaned.pow(2)
    beta = x_demeaned.dot(y_demeaned) / x_demeaned_squared.sum()
    return y_demeaned - beta * x_demeaned

print(
    df
    .with_column(residuals(pl.col("x"), pl.col("y")).alias("e"))
    .head(3) # remove this to get the entire result
)
```

The first few rows look like this:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ x         ┆ y        ┆ e         │
│ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ f64       ┆ f64      ┆ f64       │
╞═══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ -0.651791 ┆ 1.257485 ┆ -0.146135 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.174717 ┆ 1.704334 ┆ -0.260438 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.663724  ┆ 4.740446 ┆ 0.613234  │
└───────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I am asking for simple linear regression just for illustration purposes, and your answer works well for it. But what I am really asking is the framework/paradigm of using polars with other tools/packages (such as statsmodels, again, as an example just for illustration purposes). So, your solution may not extend easily if I want to switch to other models. It would be great if the answer is presented with a general extensible framework/paradigm and use simple linear regression model just as a concrete example to showcase it. Thanks!

Comment: Is there possible to implement OLS with potentially multiple independent variables just by using polars expressions?

Comment: Hi @lebesgue yes, you can achieve this via "coordinate descent" - i.e. what you would do is residualize y to *each* x col iteratively over a sufficient number of iterations to ensure convergence. you are guarenteed to achieve optimality due to the strict convexity and I've found this approach to be far more efficient than paying the overhead of unstacking/stacking and conversions to numpy