# How to return multiple stats as multiple columns in Polars grouby context?

Tags: python, python-polars

The task at hand is to do multiple linear regression over multiple columns in groupby context and return respective beta coefficients and their associated t-values in separate columns.

Below is an illustration of an attempt to do such using statsmodels.

```
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
import polars as pl
import statsmodels.api as sm


def ols_stats(s, yvar, xvars):
    df = s.struct.unnest()
    yvar = df[yvar].to_numpy()
    xvars = df[xvars].to_numpy()
    reg = sm.OLS(yvar, sm.add_constant(xvars), missing="drop").fit()
    return np.concatenate((reg.params, reg.tvalues))



df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        "y": [1, 6, 3, 2, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1],
        "x1": [1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1],
        "x2": [8, 5, 3, 6, 3, 7, 3, 2, 9, 1, 1],
    }
)

df.groupby("day").agg(
    pl.struct(["y", "x1", "x2"])
    .apply(partial(ols_stats, yvar="y", xvars=["x1", "x2"]))
    .alias("params")
)
```

The result from the code snippet above evaluates to

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ day ┆ params                              │
│ --- ┆ ---                                 │
│ i64 ┆ object                              │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2   ┆ [2.0462002  0.22397054 0.3367927... │
│ 3   ┆ [0.5 0.5 0.  0. ]                   │
│ 1   ┆ [ 4.86623165  0.64029364 -0.6598... │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

How am I supposed to split the 'params' into separate columns with one scalar value in each column?

Also, my code seems to fail at some corner cases. Below is one of them.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        "y": [1, 6, 3, 2, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, None],
        "x1": [1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1],
        "x2": [8, 5, 3, 6, 3, 7, 3, 2, 9, 1, 1],
    }
)

df.groupby("day").agg(
    pl.struct(["y", "x1", "x2"])
    .apply(partial(ols_stats, yvar="y", xvars=["x1", "x2"]))
    .alias("params")
)

>>> exceptions.ComputeError: ValueError: exog is not 1d or 2d
```

How can I make the code robust to such case?

Thanks for your help. And feel free to suggest your own solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the type of the `params` column is `object` - this is not what you want.

- You need to [return a `Series` object from your function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74906705) instead of a numpy array.

Then you can use `.arr.to_struct()` to turn the list into a struct which allows you to `.unnest()`

```
df.groupby("day").agg(
   pl.struct(["y", "x1", "x2"])
     .apply(partial(ols_stats, yvar="y", xvars=["x1", "x2"]))
     .alias("params")
).with_columns(pl.col("params").arr.to_struct()).unnest("params")
```

```
shape: (3, 7)
┌─────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ day ┆ field_0  ┆ field_1  ┆ field_2   ┆ field_3  ┆ field_4  ┆ field_5   │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64       ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64       │
╞═════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4.866232 ┆ 0.640294 ┆ -0.659869 ┆ 1.547251 ┆ 1.81586  ┆ -1.430613 │
│ 2   ┆ 2.0462   ┆ 0.223971 ┆ 0.336793  ┆ 1.524834 ┆ 0.495378 ┆ 1.091109  │
│ 3   ┆ 0.5      ┆ 0.5      ┆ 0.0       ┆ 0.0      ┆ null     ┆ null      │
└─────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to give aliases to those unnested fields?

Comment: [`.struct.rename_fields()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.struct.rename_fields.html#polars.Expr.struct.rename_fields)

Comment: have a variation of the problem for lazy dataframe here - <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631703/follow-up-how-to-return-multiple-stats-as-multiple-columns-in-polars-grouby-con>

Answer (score 0):

To convert List column to multiple columns, you can use `for` loop:

```py
df.select([
    pl.col("params").arr.get(i).alias(f"param_{i}") 
    for i in range(df["params"].arr.lengths().max())
    #                                         /
    #                                use .max() if the length of the lists
    #                                may differ from row to row
])
```