# How to apply rolling_map() in Python Polars for a function that uses multiple input columns

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a function using Polars Expressions to calculate the standard deviation of the residuals from a linear regression (courtesy of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895640/how-to-do-regression-simple-linear-for-example-in-polars-select-or-groupby-con)).

Now I would like to apply this function using a **rolling window** over a dataframe. My approaches below fail because I don't know how to pass two columns as arguments to the function, since rolling_map() applies to an Expr.

Is there a way to do this directly in Polars, or do I need to use a workaround with Pandas? Thank you for your support! (feels like I'm missing something obvious here...)

```
import polars as pl


def ols_residuals_std(x: pl.Expr, y: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    # Calculate linear regression residuals and return the standard deviation thereof
    x_center = x - x.mean()
    y_center = y - y.mean()
    beta = x_center.dot(y_center) / x_center.pow(2).sum()
    e = y_center - beta * x_center
    return e.std()


df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [45, 76, 4, 88, 66, 5, 24, 72, 93, 87, 23, 40],
                   'b': [77, 11, 56, 43, 61, 25, 63, 7, 66, 17, 64, 75]})

# Applying the function over the full length - works
df = df.with_columns(ols_residuals_std(pl.col('a'), pl.col('b')).alias('e_std'))

# Applying the function using a rolling window - fails
df.with_columns(pl.col('a').rolling_map(ols_residuals_std(pl.col('a'), pl.col('b')), window_size=4, min_periods=1).alias('e_std_win'))
df.with_columns(pl.col(['a', 'b']).rolling_map(ols_residuals_std(), window_size=4, min_periods=1).alias('e_std_win'))
```

Comment: There is always [`pl.struct`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.struct.html#polars.struct), which packs multiple expressions into one column. You could then apply `rolling_map` and unpack that one expression in `ols_residuals_std` to get the original columns back out.

Comment: @BallpointBen Afaik `rolling_map` is not implemented for `pl.struct` expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to note about in [`rolling_map`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_map.html#polars.Expr.rolling_map) is that it is used for a custom function. While your expression is defined with a function, it isn't what they mean. What they mean is a python function which takes in values and outputs a value. This is also hinted at by the name having map which coincides to `map_elements` and `map_batches`. Additionally there's a Warning that it will be extremely slow which also hints at its expectation.

To get at what you want to do, you can use [`rolling`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling.html#polars.Expr.rolling) which unfortunately doesn't infer an index column so you have to manually create it. It also doesn't accept a `UInt` as an input so you can't even use `with_row_count`. Instead do:

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(pl.int_range(0,pl.count()).cast(pl.Int64).alias('i'))
    .with_columns(
        ols_residuals_std(pl.col('a'), pl.col('b'))
        .rolling('i',period='4i').alias('e_std_win')
        )
    .drop('i')
)
shape: (12, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ e_std_win │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64       │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 45  ┆ 77  ┆ 0.0       │
│ 76  ┆ 11  ┆ 0.0       │
│ 4   ┆ 56  ┆ 26.832826 │
│ 88  ┆ 43  ┆ 23.440663 │
│ …   ┆ …   ┆ …         │
│ 93  ┆ 66  ┆ 28.72105  │
│ 87  ┆ 17  ┆ 28.981351 │
│ 23  ┆ 64  ┆ 29.063269 │
│ 40  ┆ 75  ┆ 22.362099 │
└─────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Do you know why this does not produce the same output as first using `.group_by_dynamic(pl.int_range(0, pl.count()).alias("idx"), every="1i", offset="-3i", period="4i")` and then aggregate using `ols_residuals_std`? When comparing `pl.col("a").flatten()` for this and your solution, the lists look identical. However, the results differ.