# OLS / Multiple linear regression in polars

Tags: linear-regression, python-polars

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74899658/23274857), I was wondering if there was any (fast) implementation of OLS with multiple  variables implemented in polars?

Someone mentioned 'coordinate descent', I'm wondering if a polar implementation is available?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extension called [`polars_ds`](https://github.com/abstractqqq/polars_ds_extension/blob/main/examples/basics.ipynb) that does OLS. You just just `pip install polars_ds`

See cells 6 through 12 of the link for example usage. Here's just the simplest case copy-pasted

```
# Least Square (Linear Regression)
df.select(
    pl.col("y").num.lstsq(pl.col("x1"), pl.col("x2"), add_bias=False)
)
shape: (1, 1)
y
list[f64]
[2.0, -1.0]
```

In that case the list output are the coefficients for `x1` and `x2` respectively.